# display image in draftjs editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using draftjs editor. I could render the content but I could not show images. How can i show image when using draftjs? Right now the url is only shown instead of images.The server sends the data as following

> img src="http://image_url" style="argin:30px auto; max-width: 350px;"

Sorry i could not use img tag html way so excluded the tag syntax.

```
function findImageEntities(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(character => {
    const entityKey = character.getEntity();
    return (
      entityKey !== null &&
      contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === "IMAGE"
    );
  }, callback);
}

const Image = props => {
  const { height, src, width } = props.contentState
    .getEntity(props.entityKey)
    .getData();
  return <img src={src} height={height} width={width} />;
};
class AdminEditor extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      editorContent: undefined,
      contentState: "",
      touched: false
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.htmlMarkup !== this.props.htmlMarkup) {
      const content = nextProps.htmlMarkup;
      const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(content);
      const plainState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        blocksFromHTML.entityMap
      );
      this.setState(state => ({
        editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(plainState, decorator)
      }));
    }
  }

  onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  };

  onEditorChange = editorContent => {
    this.setState({
      editorContent
    });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.props.setEditorState(
      this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText() && this.state.touched
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    const { stateOfEditor } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          tabIndex={0}
          editorState={editorState}
          initialContentState={this.props.htmlMarkup}
          toolbarClassName="home-toolbar"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          toolbar={{
            history: { inDropdown: true },
            inline: { inDropdown: false },
            link: { showOpenOptionOnHover: true },
            image: {
              uploadCallback: this.imageUploadCallBack,
              defaultSize: { height: "auto", width: "50%" }
            }
          }}
          onContentStateChange={this.onEditorChange}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminEditor;
```

exact copy of decorator is in top of the findImageEntities which i haven't pasted just to reduce the number of lines of code

Answer (score 0):

I saw the props onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange} . I doubt you're using the draft-js-wysiwyg not draft-js.
In draft-js-wysiwyg , u can visit here :
https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/589